# Store Id after authentication ASP net web forms

Tags: c#, asp.net, session, webforms, forms-authentication

I would like to save the user ID after the forms authentication is made through email and password.  I am currently using a session to do so;

However the session and the form authentication have different timeouts and because the session is a server type of variable when one user is logged in if I login with a different username on another machine the session simple changes its value and that is a major issue.

Besides Caching is there any other way to accomplish it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can store user ID in expanded authentication cookie. On authorization routine compose custom cookie and add it to response:

```
var ticket = new FormsAuthenticationTicket(1, userName, DateTime.Now, DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(60), false, userId.ToString()));
HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies.Add(new HttpCookie(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName, FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(ticket)) { HttpOnly = true });
```

You can decrypt that cookie for authenticated request and find out what was user ID:

```
HttpCookie authCookie = Context.Request.Cookies[FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName];  
FormsAuthenticationTicket ticket = FormsAuthentication.Decrypt(authCookie.Value);
int iserId = int.Parse(authTicket.UserData);
```